# How to load log file into Hive table using RegexSerDe?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I have a log file having the below format from which I would like to extract `ip, datetime and uri` and load into a table.

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:17:09:01 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/search/Main/SearchResult?scope=text&search=Joris%20*Benschop[^A-Za-z] HTTP/1.1" 200 4284
```

I am able to do that by loading log file rows as a single string into table as below and by using `regexp_extract`.

`create table logs( line string);`

`load data local inpath '.../mylog.log' into table logs;`

`select 
    regexp_extract(line, '(.*) (- -) \\[(.*) -.*\\] \\"GET (.*)\\?',1),--ip
    regexp_extract(line, '(.*) (- -) \\[(.*) -.*\\] \\"GET (.*)\\?',3),--datetime
    regexp_extract(line, '(.*) (- -) \\[(.*) -.*\\] \\"GET (.*)\\?',4) --uri
from logs limit 10;`

```
+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--+
|      _c0      |          _c1          |                    _c2                     |
+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--+
| 64.242.88.10  | 07/Mar/2004:17:09:01  | /twiki/bin/search/Main/SearchResult        |
| 64.242.88.10  | 07/Mar/2004:17:10:20  | /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/TextFormattingRules  |
+---------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+--+
```

What I would like to do is to create a table specifying SerDe properties and load it without using `regexp_extract` function.  I tried the below and its not working.

```
create table logs (
    ip string,
    day timestamp,
    url string)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = 
    "(.*) [^- - \[](.*) [^-.*\]] \"([^GET].*\?)");

load data local inpath ".../mylog.log" into table logs;
```

I appreciate some help and direction.

Comment: Your serde doesn't match the regex you used earlier. You're now trying to capture the `GET`. Also, did you only want to capture GET requests?

Comment: The documentation seems to have exactly what you want... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `day` cannot be timestamp since it is not in ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`)
2. Escaping should be done with double backslash (`\\`)
3. The regular expression should cover the whole record (in this case end with `.*`)

---

```
create external table logs 
(
    ip  string
   ,day string
   ,url string
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(\\S+).*?\\[(.*?)\\s.*?(/.*?)\\?.*")
;
```

---

```
select * from logs
;
```

---

```
+--------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|      ip      |         day          |                 url                 |
+--------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 64.242.88.10 | 07/Mar/2004:17:09:01 | /twiki/bin/search/Main/SearchResult |
+--------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Aha, missed that bit about `day`. Thats why I was seeing NULL.